# Retrieve all registered users in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database in nodejs.

I simply want to fetch all the users that exists in my firebase database.

Currently I am trying this but it is only return one single user:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBmgbfgdhs4efg9gFo",
    authDomain: "my-test-app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://my-test-app-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "my-test-app",
    storageBucket: "my-die-app.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "534345345",
    appId: "1:534345345:web:cceb16e6vvdd456",
    measurementId: "G-YDZ8Y87GETR",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");

ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach((child) => {

        console.log(child)
    });
});
```

In firebase users I can only see this single user aswell, but infact I have more users there:

```
{
  "XG0hYDjhekjdfJX5zLmfUFPQBifkmZA3": [
    "XG0hYDjhekjdfJX5zLmfUFPQBifkmZA3",
    "user1@gmail.com",
    "835457568",
    "Michael James ",
    "user1@gmail.com"
  ]
}
```

And this is the only user I am getting in code aswell.

I am not the owner of this database, may be thats the reason?

Is  there any specific way to retrieve all users list?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data that exists under the `/users` node in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: As Puf requested, you should add the shape of your data here (redact sensitive information). If Renaud's answer didn't help, that means that it's something on the database side that is causing your problem, so without that information, we can't help.

Comment: Could you produce the users collection

Answer (score 3):

I believe the question answers itself

> In firebase users I can only see this single user

If there is only only user node in the `/users` node as shown in your question

```
users {
  "XG0hYDjhekjdfJX5zLmfUFPQBifkmZA3": [
    "XG0hYDjhekjdfJX5zLmfUFPQBifkmZA3",
    "user1@gmail.com",
    "835457568",
    "Michael James ",
    "user1@gmail.com"
  ]
}
```

that means only one node exists - therefore only one node can be retrieved.

The confusion may be that while Firebase has `users`  that can authenticate, those users are stored in the Firebase back-end server only. It doesn't necessarily mean other user data was written to the `/users` node.

In other words, if the app code does not specifically write data to `/users`, it won't exist.

Check your authentication code and see if it writes data to `/users` at some point - if not, there's your problem.

If that's the issue, which I suspect it is, you can't retrieve a list of Firebase users from the SDK directly, but you can using [Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) coupled with  [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

Here's an example: [Get All Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users)

Alternatively (and my suggested path), you can also add code to the app so when users authenticate, if their users node doesn't exist within `/users`, create it (using the users uid returned from the Auth parameter as the node key)

Answer (score 0):

What user are you logged in as? Is that the user you can see? What are your Firebase security rules like?

If you have reasonably secure rules setup, that would be the reason users can only see their own nodes.

See these docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization